# What does mean 'las' in R

Tags: r

```
boxplot(df01, names.arg = names, col = rainbow(12), horiz=T, las = 2)
```

in this case what does mean 'las' ??? I tried from 0 to 3, but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: It controls the direction of the axis labels.  See `?par` for details.

Comment: I'd ask if you tried it without, but ... your plot here is shown where `las` is not 2; `las=2` means `always perpendicular to the axis` ([ref](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)), so your x-axis numbers should be rotating 90 degrees according to that. (I'm assuming you're using `base::boxplot` and not a modification of it.) When in doubt about a plotting argument, change/omit it and look at the change produced by that change.

Comment: Try: `par(mfrow=1:2); boxplot(df01, names.arg = names, col = rainbow(12), horiz=T, las = 2); boxplot(df01, names.arg = names, col = rainbow(12), horiz=T)` to compare side-by-side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is documented in the function help page.

Comment: `las = "Label of Axis Style"`, see for more (not so obvious) abbreviations in R: https://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/05/abbreviations-of-r-commands-explained.html